# Dapper support for portable library project

Tags: dapper, portable-class-library

Is there som requisite that block Dapper use in a PortableLibraryProject? I'm trying to create the data access library that will be used in a wp7 and a WPF application.

WP7 app will also work in offline mode so I can't rely on a common external webservice

Comment: Do you mean to use it from a Portable Class Library or to compile it as Portable Class Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper cannot be compiled as a Portable Class Library because there's no support for Reflection.Emit and System.Data

Answer (score 0):

Dapper needs to be compiled as Portable Class Library to be able to use it from a Portable Class Library

Comment: yes ok, i was asking if there's some requirements that require a standard assembly..